# Testing my program?

Tags: java

I already have the class I need to implement in to my code. The instructions are: Code a testing program/class. This should construct or instantiate objects of the class you coded in step #1. Your testing program should call every method to make sure they work. You should construct at least two objects – one with the default constructor and one with the “other” constructor. For the second scenario, ask the user what values for (radius and) height. You may use any input and output that you want for this.

This is what I have so far and I'm stuck:

```
public class Cube 
{

   private double height;

   public Cube(){
      height = 1.0;
   }

   public Cube(double h){
      height = h;
   }

   public double getHeight(){
      return height;
   }

   public void setHeight(double h){
      height = h;
   }

   public double calcVolume() {
      return height*height*height;
   }

   public double calcSurface(){
      return height*height*6;
   }

   public String toString(){
      return this.toString();
   }

   public boolean equals(Cube c){
      return (c.getHeight() == this.height);
   }

}


import java.util.*
public class TestTheCube

{
   public static void main(String[] args)

   {

   Cube cube1 = new Cube();
   Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter a height as a positive number");
   double height = kb.nextDouble();

   Cube cube2 = new Cube(height);

   System.out.println(

   }

}
```

Comment: You should share the code directly here and avoid the links for this purpose. As the links might be broken in future and this question will not act as reference point for future readers. Plus, share more details about what are you stuck at like the exception stack trace or the expected output versus actual output

Comment: Looking at ur TestTheCube.java, you've already create 2 instance of Cube. So what you need to do is to invoke the instance method of each object.

Comment: Simply call each method, print the output and whether it matches the expected value.

Comment: I'm at a loss on how to do either of those at this point. My brain is fried.

Comment: @BalwinderSingh the problem is it doesn't allow very long code

Comment: @Josh It does, as you can verify in the edited question

Comment: Just to point out, your `toString()` method seem fishy. If u have issue with that start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I've invoked `calcVolume()` of `cube1` and `cube2`.

```
   Cube cube1 = new Cube();
   Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter a height as a positive number");
   double height = kb.nextDouble();

   Cube cube2 = new Cube(height);

   System.out.println("Cube 1's volume = "+cube1.calcVolume());
   System.out.println("Cube 2's volume = "+cube2.calcVolume());
   .....//repeat for every instance method you have.
```

Comment: But that doesn't use the number they entered in does it?

Comment: It does. For `cube2` you initialized the Cube with the `height` entered by the user. When `calcVolume()` is invoked on `cube2`, the volume is calculated based on the height provided by the input.

Comment: -Enter a height as a positive number: 10  
  -Cube 1 1.0  
  -Cube 2 surface = 1000.0  
  -Cube 1 6.0  
  -Cube 2 surface = 600.0

Comment: `cube1` uses the default constructor which sets the height to `1.0` hence 1*1*1 = 1.0.

Comment: Ah okay. Am I missing any callouts?

Comment: Just check that u invoke all the instance method. `calcVolume`, `calcSurface`, `equals`